# How can I completely disengage a GFCI outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have 2 GFCI outlets under the peninsula in my kitchen.  I never use these outlets and would like to disconnect them and remove the outlets so I can panel over them. These are on a circuit with other GFCI outlets.  Can I simply disconnect the outlets and place wire nuts on each wire and panel over the holes? Or do I have to connect some of the wires to keep the entire circuit engaged?

Comment: Can you post a picture or a diagram of how your circuit is laid out? If the outlets are daisy chained, you will need to connect some of the wires.

Comment: You cannot "panel over them" - you will need an access to the junction box - which can be a blank cover.

Comment: I would not do this. Period. You say you never use them, but creating a code violation by removing them makes no sense at all IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't -- you can't "panel over" boxes and make them inaccessible as a result and you *must* have at least one receptacle installed and hot on a 24" by 12" or larger peninsula.

Comment: Well, you could terminate the wires and put a blank faceplate over the box. That plate _must_ be exposed, but it could be a wood matching the paneling...

Comment: @keshlam -- true; however, the requirement for a receptacle for the peninsula still makes the OP's request a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply wirenut like colors together inside each box, but there is a critical caveat to that: you *must* have GFCI protection on your kitchen circuits. I'm guessing these two outlets are the first outlets on each of the two required circuits for the kitchen, so you will then have to replace the GFCI protection - most likely by replacing the breakers with GFCI breakers.

Comment: Questioner states that the other outlets are ALSO GFCI's - some electricians don't believe in wiring anything to the "load" terminals and install this way (probably at higher profit, but the claim is "less confusion about why an outlet tripped, when the outlet is not the one with the GFCI, and the breaker isn't tripped.) That probably has a shred of truth attached to it, though it does not fly in my house.

Comment: Good point...  another point - the NEC (as of my last reading of it) requires outlets be present and hot on kitchen islands above a certain size. If you do remove these outlets, you may find yourself with a code vioaltion that has to be remedied before you're able to sell the house.

Comment: I'm not concerned about selling the house, but I do want to make sure that whatever I do is safe.

Comment: If you want to be truly safe leave them alone.